# Facebook App Can't Submit Data Handling Questions

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am not sure why I can't submit these data handling questions for my facebook app. I am not able to contact their support and don't know how to resolve this. Does anyone know why?

[image]

Comment: The only possible answer to this question is "contact Facebook support".

Comment: what did you do to get past this bs?

Comment: Add Data Proccesser